# How to get document id after creation Firestore ios?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Pretty new to Firestore. Is there a way to get ID or reference to a newly created document?

```
firestore.collection(myCollection).document().setData(["myData": data]) { err in
   if let err = err {
      print("Error writing document: \(err)")
   } else {
      print("Document successfully written!")
   }
}
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get it **before** the document is created, because it's generated on the client when you create the [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference).

```
let ref = firestore.collection(myCollection).document()
// ref is a DocumentReference
let id = ref.documentID
// id contains the random ID
ref.setData(...)
```